# How to remove all the empty new lines in a document with one command?

Tags: vim

My document looks something like this:

```
Line number one

Line number two

Line number three
```

I want the whole document to look like this:

```
Line number one
Line number two
Line number three
```

In other words, to remove all the empty lines. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `:g/^$/d`, which will remove all blank lines. The `g` indicates `global`, the `^$` is a regular expression that basically means 'match lines that start and end with nothing in between', and the `d` means `delete`. You can mix and match as much as you need :)

Another space-related command that may come in handy if you have random whitespace is `:%s/\s\+$//`, which trims any trailing whitespace (as @Bernhard points out, the `$` operator means that you have a max of one occurrence per line, so the `g` is unnecessary).

Per the update, possible that the lines already contain whitespace, in which case `:g/^\s*$/d` should work.

Comment: Thanks! But strange, most of empty lines were deleted, but some (very few) remained. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: @alexchenco No prob! Not sure if you have space highlighting turned on, but it is possible there is additional whitespace in there. Try running `g/^\s*$/d` and see if that gets rid of them.

Comment: Hey Thanks! `g/^\s*$/d` did it. Strange, it was because of trailing white space? I'll accept the answer once 3 mins has passed. By the way, how can revert that with Vim? (to add a blank lines after each new line?)

Comment: @alexchenco Sweet! That was because of whitespace that was on the line (in general, I guess that the second answer is probably better to account for cases like that :) ). You had some spaces/tabs/etc. that caused `^$` to skip it (since there was something between the beginning and end of the line); adding in the `\s*` to form `^\s*$` means 'from the beginning of the line, match one or more whitespace characters and then the end of the line'.

Comment: @RocketDonkey I don't think you need the find `g` flag in the second example.

Comment: Ah good call @Bernhard - guess it is a bit redundant huh? Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey It does no harm either :)

Comment: @Bernhard :) Quick question on your edit - I'm going to switch it back to 'the `%` operator' but qualify it with 'acts on the entire file' - does that work for you?

Comment: @RocketDonkey No, the `%` has nothing to do with it. `g` only means to continu substituting after the first occurence **within** a line. Suppose you want to delete all spaces, then you need the `g`.

Comment: @Bernhard I just tried it again, and `%s/\s\+$//` removed all trailing whitespace from all lines in the file (which is what I was aiming for; adding the `g` works as well). Is that not the behavior your see?

Comment: @RocketDonkey Compare with `%s/\s\+//g` (no `$`) and '.s/\s\+$//' (`.` instead of `%`).

Comment: @Bernhard The first one replaces all spaces (including non-trailing, which wasn't what I was going for), the second only operates on the line. My understanding is that when the `%` is added, we perform the operation on all lines across the file, and the `\s\+$` indicates that we remove all sequences where 1 or more spaces make up the line ending. Using the `.` operator refers only to the current line I believe, so your second example trims the trailing whitespace, but you need to change the `.` to a `%` to have it affect all lines. Am I missing something (I usually am :) )?

Comment: @RocketDonkey My point was, as you only have one occurance of `$` anyhow, the `g` becomes obsolete. Omiting `g` will make the subtitute command stop searching a line after the first hit. This on a per line basis.

Comment: @Bernhard Ah gotcha - I guess in this case it is somewhat moot since the first hit will be the only hit (as it is just the trailing space). I see what you're saying now - sorry for being dense :)

Answer (score 5):

The command I use is

```
:v/./d
```

[The v command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3avglobal) matches the lines that do *not* match the given pattern.
It was inherited from [ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29).

Comment: Thanks! How about doing the opposite? Adding an empty line after line breaks?

Comment: `:%s/[\r\n][\r\n]*/&&/g` or just `:%s/\n/&&/` when working with Unix text files

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really wanted to know that!